# Keyboard shortcut to summon screenshot tool

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-screenshot

Currently, I go to dash, type `Screenshot` to start the screenshot tool. Is there any keyboard shortcut to summon it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but as far as I know you can create custom shortcut to launch the Gnome Screenshot.

- Navigate to *Settings > Devices > Keyboard*.
- Assign new custom keyboard shortcut by clicking <kbd>+</kbd> button on bottom of page.
- In the command section, type following.

  ```
   gnome-screenshot --interactive
  ```
- Save the changes

You can now bring up Gnome Screenshot by clicking keyboard combination.

If you wish to screenshot your whole desktop, simply pressing <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will capture your screen immediately, in default Ubuntu it will then ask you directory to store the saved screenshot.

On the other hand, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> will capture your currently active window.

Comment: In default Ubuntu, and in many other desktop environments, Print Screen is setup to do a screen shot of the entire screen, Alt+Print Screen of the selected window. You may want to add that to your answer.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks, added.